# How to open a program as root user?

Tags: permissions, git, sublime-text

I'm coding my project using Sublime Text code editor. My project folder has not root permissions, so every time I save my changes on sublime text, I have to enter the password. To prevent that, I can change permissions of the folder using chmod, but when I pushing the code to Git, it give errors that saying my all files has been changed and I have to add and commit every file.

How I can solve this?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a little? What do you mean by "My project folder has not root permissions"? 
If you need to run sublime as root, start it from command line with sudo and not from GUI.
BUT - you really should not use root for development, maybe if you provide more info on what you are doing we could help...

Comment: "My project folder has not root permissions" correct, and it does not need it either so I don't see a problem? "I can change permissions of the folder using chmod" True but that will get you other problems. How about doing it correctly? have your user added to the same group as the project folder for instance.

Comment: Only I need to avoid entering password at every time I save the code. I thought that it will be solve if I open the editor as root user